# Symfony2 embedded form, Class does not exist - A2lix translations

Tags: php, symfony, a2lix-translation

I'm using two entities in one form, ContentType in EstablishmentType. If I use only "classic" field type I got no errors. But when I add the field 'translations' with 'a2lix_translations_gedmo' as type in ContentType it return an ReflectionException "Class does not exists".

Translations with A2lix are working fine in others entities.

As anyone an idea ?

Code below:

**EstablishmentType.php**

```
namespace Demo\FoundationBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class EstablishmentType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('content', new ContentType(),array(
                'data_class'=>null
           ))
            ->add('translations', 'a2lix_translations_gedmo',array(
                'translatable_class' => "Demo\FoundationBundle\Entity\Establishment",
            ))
            ->add('category','entity',array(
                'class'=>'Demo\FoundationBundle\Entity\Category',
                "required"=>true,
                'label'=>'Categorie'
            ))
            ->add('file','file')
            ->add('participationLevel','number',array(
                'label'=>'Taux de participation'
            ))
        ;
    }
```

**ContentType.php**
    namespace Demo\FoundationBundle\Form;

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class ContentType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('type','choice',
                array(
                    'choices'=>array(
                        'text'=>'Texte',
                        'highlight'=>'Mise en avant'
                    ),
                    'required'=>false
                ))
            ->add('translations', 'a2lix_translations_gedmo',array(
                'translatable_class' => "Demo\FoundationBundle\Entity\Content",
            ))
            ->add('class','text',array(
                'label'=>'Classe css',
                'required'=>false
            ))
            ->add('column_nb','number',array(
                'label'=>'Nombre de colonnes',
                'required'=>false
            ))
        ;
    }
```

Stack Trace

```
ReflectionException: Class  does not exist
    at n/a
        in /var/www/html/Demo/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 6969

    at ReflectionClass->__construct('')
        in /var/www/html/Demo/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 6969

    at Doctrine\Common\Persistence\AbstractManagerRegistry->getManagerForClass(null)
        in /var/www/html/Demo/vendor/a2lix/translation-form-bundle/A2lix/TranslationFormBundle/TranslationForm/GedmoTranslationForm.php line 45

    at A2lix\TranslationFormBundle\TranslationForm\GedmoTranslationForm->getGedmoConfig(null)
        in /var/www/html/Demo/vendor/a2lix/translation-form-bundle/A2lix/TranslationFormBundle/TranslationForm/GedmoTranslationForm.php line 67

    at A2lix\TranslationFormBundle\TranslationForm\GedmoTranslationForm->getTranslatableFields(null)
        in /var/www/html/Demo/vendor/a2lix/translation-form-bundle/A2lix/TranslationFormBundle/TranslationForm/TranslationForm.php line 48

    at A2lix\TranslationFormBundle\TranslationForm\TranslationForm->getChildrenOptions(null, array('block_name' => null, 'disabled' => false, 'label' => null, 'label_format' => null, 'translation_domain' => null, 'auto_initialize' => true, 'trim' => true, 'required' => true, 'read_only' => false, 'max_length' => null, 'pattern' => null, 'property_path' => null, 'mapped' => true, 'by_reference' => true, 'virtual' => null, 'compound' => true, 'method' => 'POST', 'action' => '', 'post_max_size_message' => 'The uploaded file was too large. Please try to upload a smaller file.', 'error_mapping' => array(), 'cascade_validation' => false, 'invalid_message' => 'This value is not valid.', 'invalid_message_parameters' => array(), 'allow_extra_fields' => false, 'extra_fields_message' => 'This form should not contain extra fields.', 'csrf_protection' => true, 'csrf_field_name' => '_token', 'csrf_message' => 'The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form.', 'csrf_provider' => object(CsrfTokenManager), 'intention' => null, 'locales' => array('fr', 'de', 'en'), 'fields' => array(), 'attr' => array(), 'data_class' => null, 'empty_data' => object(Closure), 'error_bubbling' => true, 'label_attr' => array(), 'inherit_data' => false, 'validation_groups' => null, 'constraints' => array(), 'csrf_token_manager' => object(CsrfTokenManager), 'csrf_token_id' => null, 'translatable_class' => 'Demo\FoundationBundle\Entity\Content'))
        in /var/www/html/Demo/vendor/a2lix/translation-form-bundle/A2lix/TranslationFormBundle/Form/EventListener/GedmoTranslationsListener.php line 45

    at A2lix\TranslationFormBundle\Form\EventListener\GedmoTranslationsListener->preSetData(object(FormEvent), 'form.pre_set_data', object(EventDispatcher))
        in  line 

    at call_user_func(array(object(GedmoTranslationsListener), 'preSetData'), object(FormEvent), 'form.pre_set_data', object(EventDispatcher))
        in /var/www/html/Demo/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 1834

    at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(array(array(object(GedmoTranslationsListener), 'preSetData')), 'form.pre_set_data', object(FormEvent))
        in /var/www/html/Demo/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 1763

    at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch('form.pre_set_data', object(FormEvent))
        in /var/www/html/Demo/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/ImmutableEventDispatcher.php line 43

    at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ImmutableEventDispatcher->dispatch('form.pre_set_data', object(FormEvent))
        in /var/www/html/Demo/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php line 342

    at Symfony\Component\Form\Form->setData(null)
        in /var/www/html/Demo/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/DataMapper/PropertyPathMapper.php line 57

    at Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\DataMapper\PropertyPathMapper->mapDataToForms(object(ArrayCollection), object(RecursiveIteratorIterator))
        in /var/www/html/Demo/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php line 396

    at Symfony\Component\Form\Form->setData(object(ArrayCollection))
        in /var/www/html/Demo/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/DataMapper/PropertyPathMapper.php line 57

    at Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\DataMapper\PropertyPathMapper->mapDataToForms(object(Establishment), object(RecursiveIteratorIterator))
        in /var/www/html/Demo/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php line 396

    at Symfony\Component\Form\Form->setData(object(Establishment))
        in /var/www/html/Demo/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php line 488

    at Symfony\Component\Form\Form->initialize()
        in /var/www/html/Demo/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormBuilder.php line 226

    at Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder->getForm()
        in /var/www/html/Demo/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactory.php line 39

    at Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactory->create(object(EstablishmentType), object(Establishment))
        in /var/www/html/Demo/src/Demo/AdminBundle/Controller/Est/NewController.php line 17

    at Demo\AdminBundle\Controller\Est\NewController->indexAction()
        in  line 

    at call_user_func_array(array(object(NewController), 'indexAction'), array())
        in /var/www/html/Demo/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 3109

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1')
        in /var/www/html/Demo/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 3071

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
        in /var/www/html/Demo/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 3222

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
        in /var/www/html/Demo/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2444

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
        in /var/www/html/Demo/web/app_dev.php line 28
```

Answer (score 0):

The bundle itself will handle the translation class just fine if you've defined the `data_class` in `ContentType::configureOptions`:

```
->add('translations', 'a2lix_translations_gedmo',array(
    'translatable_class' => "Demo\FoundationBundle\Entity\Content",
))
```

could just become:

```
->add('translations', 'a2lix_translations')
```

... if you add

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    parent::configureOptions($resolver);

    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\YourEntity'
    ));
}
```

The translation configuration is not handled via the `FormType`, but should be handled via the entity.

Comment: I already had the setDefaultOptions() method with the data_class in it. I added the parent::configureOptions($resolver) in it but the error turn to 

FatalErrorException in DefaultTranslationsListener.php line 43: Error: Class name must be a valid object or a string

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the current master version (2.0) of the bundle, `a2lix_translations_gedmo` doesn't exist anymore.

You've to use

```
$builder->add('translations', 'a2lix_translatedEntity', array(
    'class' => 'Demo\FoundationBundle\Entity\Content',
    'translation_property' => 'text',
    'multiple' => true,
));
```

Comment: I'm on an existing project which use a2lix_translations_gedmo ~1.2